# Security in Play 2.2.x

Tags: security, scala, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to secure my play application but I have no idea where to start. In play tutorial I have not found any chapter about that topic. As far as I see security topic is changing between play versions. So what are You guys using to secure Yours applications.
I'm new in Play so please forgive me if I'm asking obvious questions.

**Edit**:
Ok, maby question was't clear enough(I'm really sorry about that). When talking about security I mean that I need something to deal with users credentials and tool which allows me to restrict access to some pages and eventually to some rest actions in my application.

**Edit2**:
I'll try deadbolt2 now and we'll see how does it works. But I still encurage You guys to share Your knowledge about Play security with others:)

Comment: What do you mean by secure your application? Adding a password protection to some pages? Protect a whole folder? Avoid security problems such as SQL injections, cross-site scripting, ... ?

Comment: Answers depending of what really the question is are : 1) deal with sessions, cookies, ... 2) htaccess 3) play framework will avoid such things if you use it correctly

Comment: You have two possibilities: define [filter](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaHttpFilters) or own action - see @Mikesname answer

Answer (score 4):

The documentation seems to still be a bit lacklustre on this topic, but essentially, authentication/authorisation functionality is usually performed using Action composition, which is the basis of reusable controller code in Play. There an example [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Security%24%24AuthenticatedBuilder%24) (also linked from the [docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaActionsComposition) that should help give you the general idea.)

Action composition in Play 2.2.x is done using [ActionBuilders](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder). These take a block which accepts a request and returns a `Future[SimpleResult]`. This allows the action builder to either execute the given block, or return a different `Future[SimpleResult]` (say, an `Unauthorized` in the case that a user's credentials did not check out.)

In our app we use the [Play2-auth](https://github.com/t2v/play2-auth) module for handling authentication with session cookies. This has (just) been updated to work with Play 2.2.x but uses a slightly different mechanism for action composition ([stackable controllers](https://github.com/t2v/stackable-controller).) You might be best off working out how the precise functionality you need can be accomplished just using the native framework tools before adding a dependency to it.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply. I've just red about Play2-auth and they say that deadbolt2 is for java and Play2-auth is for scala but it's not true. Deadbolt2 is also for scala. So I'll try with that(deadbolt2) and we'll see how does it works.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other answers but just add that I use securesocial to integrate with other auth providers (google, FB, etc...), so I don't have to do auth myself.  It's quite easy to get up and running.

https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial

Answer (score 1):

Access control, security, etc. is a very wide topic, because it means very different things depending on context. This may be one of the reasons why Play has little documentation for it, which puzzled me at the beginning as well.

Play2 has some [security helpers](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Security%24), namely it's the `Authenticated` method, for some insights on how to use it, check the comments in the source code. Its a simple method that you could implement yourself, and most do. It, essentially, just proposes a structure for where to place your methods that would check if request is authenticated and what to do if it's not.

Play2 also has some cryptography logic, which is used for signing cookies.

That's about it, you don't have any more pre-built security structures, but that's a good thing, because you don't want the framework making decisions like that for you, if it doesn't know in what context it will be used.

What is essential is to go and research how attacks relevant to your application are carried out, best practices and so on. I recommend going to OWASP, particularly the [OWASP Cheat Sheets](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cheat_Sheets). If the list of Cheat Sheets seems intimidating start with [the OWASP Top Ten Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Top_Ten_Cheat_Sheet). Don't mind the large volume of information, it's very useful knowledge.